# Magento 2, How to include unsubscribe link in transaction email

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, email, transactional-mail

Is there a out-of-the-box way of including an unsubscribe link in transactional emails inside of Magento 2?

I tried utilizing:

```
<a href="{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}">
{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}
</a>
```

Which is used in the email newsletter templates but this does not work inside of a transactional email.

Comment: Is this new order email?

Comment: No, I'm trying to include an unsubscribe link inside the subscription confirmation email to keep a client compliant in their country's electronic communication laws. Something along the lines of "You can unsubscribe at anytime using the following link".

Comment: Create object of `Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber` & call `getUnsubscriptionLink` function

Comment: @AnkitShah, I have tried the same that you have mentioned and then I got the unsubscription link in mail. The unsubscription process was working fine. But the probelm is it return "You have logged out." success message. How can I solve that?

Comment: This `{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}` works only in Newsletter Queue emails. I need in the Newsletter Subscription success email to add unsubscribe link but this `<a href="{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}">Unsubscribe</a>` is not working Anyone find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

it's working for me.

```
<a href="{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}">Unsubscribe</a>
```

Comment: how to add subscribe link?

Comment: This answer only works for Newsletter emails, not the success email that the question is asking about.